# Detect the CSS selectors that affect a given node

Tags: html, css, dom

I would like to know if it may be possible and there is a reasonably efficient way to detect all CSS selectors that affect a given HTML node. This is somehow the inverse problem to the usual parsing of CSS styles and HTML, i.e. get all nodes affected by a a set of CSS selectors.

I would like to avoid parsing all CSS styles when I only need the styles for a given node.

Just to clarify: I would like to do it within PHP or JavaScript (although a solution in other programming language could also be of help).

Comment: Use the developer tools ... GoogleChrome inspector `F12`

Comment: Are you trying to see what styles you've got acting on a div/a tag etc? Why don't you use chrome dev tools/firebug/etc?

Comment: Obviously I would like to do it within my own code (PHP, JavaScript or the like)

Comment: My problem is that I do not know where to start so I was wondering if anyone could throw a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an interesting question:

1. Given a CSS selector, we can determine which DOM nodes it is applied to.
2. Given a DOM node, can we determine which CSS selectors apply to it?

For example, given this HTML:

```
<div id="D">
  <ul class="U">
    <li class="L">This is a test
  </ul>
</div>
```

… and this CSS:

```
div     {font-size: 15pt;}
#D      {color: brown;}
ul.U    {background: pink;}
ul.U li {border: 1px solid red; color: green}
li      {color: purple;}
.L      {color: red; background:yellow;}
```

… can we determine that all the above styles apply to the LI node?

(An interesting follow-up question may be *why* its color is green rather than red – even though its background is yellow.)

The snippet below lists all CSS selectors belonging to a given node.

It works by finding all selectors in all stylesheets, loading them in jQuery's $ function, and comparing them against the given node *and* all its parent nodes.

```js
function showStyles(selector) {
  var jo= $(selector)[0],
      s= '<tr class="heading2"><td colspan="2">'+selector;

  for(var st in styles) {
    $(st).each(function() {
      var jp= jo;
      do {
        if(this === jp) {
          s+= '<tr><td>'+st+'<td>'+styles[st];
        }
        jp= jp.parentNode;
      } while(jp);
    });
  }
  $('#T tr:last').after(s);
} //showStyles

var styles = {},
    sheets = document.styleSheets;
for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  var rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
  for (var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++) {
    var sp= rules[r].selectorText.split(',');
    for(var j = 0 ; j < sp.length ; j++) {
      var spt= sp[j].trim();
      if(!styles[spt]) styles[spt]= '';
      styles[spt]+= rules[r].style.cssText;
    }
  }
}

showStyles('.L');
showStyles('#D');
```

```css
body, table {
  font: 9pt verdana;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
caption {
  background: #246;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
.heading1 {
  background: #246;
  color: white;
}
.heading2 {
  background: #def;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div     {font-size: 15pt;}
#D      {color: brown;}
ul.U    {background: pink;}
ul.U li {border: 1px solid red; color: green}
li      {color: purple;}
.L      {color: red; background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="D">
 <ul class="U">
  <li class="L">This is a test
 </ul>
</div>

<table id="T">
  <tr class="heading1"><th>Selector<th>Style
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It seems like an interesting approach to the problem. I will do some testing to check how it performs for large CSS stylesheets.

Comment: Sure thing.  Don't understand why your question got downvoted, because I can see how this functionality might come in handy.